# java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit VS java.time.temporal.ChronoField

Tags: java-8, java-time

While looking at java 8 Time API I see a lot of methods expect as a parameter [ChronoUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) (implementation of [TemporalUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalUnit.html)) as [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) while other expect a [ChronoField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html) (implementation of [TemporalField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalField.html)) as [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#get-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-).

Could anyone help me clarify the designers decision when a method is expecting to use a ChronoUnit and when a ChronoField and what are their differences?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Units are used to measure a *quantity* of time - years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds. For example, the second is an [SI unit](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/second.html).

By contrast, fields are how humans generally refer to time, which is in *parts*. If you look at a digital clock, the seconds count from 0 up to 59 and then go back to 0 again. This is a *field* - "second-of-minute" in this case, formed by counting seconds within a minute. Similarly, days are counted within a month, and months within a year. To define a complete point on the time-line you have to have a set of linked fields, eg:

- second-of-minute
- minute-of-hour
- hour-of-day
- day-of-month
- month-of-year
- year (-of-forever)

The `ChronoField` API exposes the two parts of second-of-minute. Use `getBaseUnit()` to get "seconds" and `getRangeUnit()` to get "minutes".

The `Chrono` part of the name refers to the fact that the definitions are chronology-neutral. Specifically, this means that the unit or field has a meaning only when associated with a calendar system, or `Chronology`. An example of this is the Coptic chronology, where there are 13 months in a year. Despite this being different to the common civil/ISO calendar system, the `ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR` constant can still be used.

The `TemporalUnit` and `TemporalField` interfaces provide the higher level abstraction, allowing units/fields that are not chronology-neutral to be added and processed.

Comment: Aren’t we actually using year-of-era? If we say, we have the year 2017, we mean “2017 AD”, not “2017th year since the big bang”…

Comment: You can use "year-of-era" and "era (-of-forever)" together as an alternative to "year (-of-forever)". Its just a choice in the API.

Comment: Would it be reasonable to say that fields are "what dates/times expose" and units are "what durations/periods expose?" In other words, it's "location in time" vs. "quantity of time?" That seems compatible with what you're saying, and it fits the idea that duration/period "expose" (i.e., have `get`/`with` methods for) _units_ but dates/times "expose" _fields_ (but _add/subtract units_, since those are quantities!). But I may be oversimplifying.

Comment: That seems OK as a way to look at it.

Comment: Amazing explanation! (And yes, I know you're the main guy behind the library. :-) )

Answer (score 6):

A `TemporalUnit` serves as general unit of time measurement. Therefore it can be used in determining the [size of temporal amount](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) between two given points in time (in abstract sense).

However, a `TemporalField` is not necessarily related to any kind of (abstract) time axis and usually represents a detail value of a point in time. Example: A month is only one component of a complete calendar date consisting of year, month and day-of-month.

Some people might argue that a calendar month and the month unit could be interpreted more or less as equivalent. Older libraries like `java.util.Calendar` don't make this difference. However, field and unit are used in a very different way as shown above (composing points in time versus measuring temporal amount).

Interestingly, the JDK-8-designers have decided that a field must have a [base unit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalField.html#getBaseUnit--) which is not null (I am personally not happy about this narrowing decision because I can imagine other fields not necessarily having a base unit). In case of months it is quite trivial. **In case of days, we have different fields with the same base unit DAYS**, for example day-of-month, day-of-year, day-of-week. This 1:n-relationship justifies the separation of units and fields in context of JSR-310 (aka java.time-package).

Comment: `I can imagine other fields not necessarily having a base unit`.. You mean you can imagine some `TemporalField`s not necessarily having a base unit? Can you give an example?

Comment: @KorayTugay Such other fields are not possible within the design limitations of JSR-310, but if you look at other time libs like the implementations of Chinese calendar in ICU4J (see field [IS_LEAP_MONTH](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/Calendar.html#IS_LEAP_MONTH)) or in my lib Time4J ([SOLAR_TERM](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/calendar/ChineseCalendar.html#SOLAR_TERM) has no base unit). One consequence of such design limitations is that the Chinese calendar is nigh to impossible to be implemented in JSR-310.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are there any books that you can suggest for a beginner who is interested in understanding `time`? I have this in mind: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0041T51EQ/?coliid=I2AERNTQAJDDEU&colid=3MYTNB1D7HN5R&psc=0&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it but would you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @KorayTugay The book preview you linked sounds interesting but a) I cannot say much because I have not got it to read and b) it appears to be a general book about time not about time programming.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to ask you if you would have a book to recommend on time in general..

Comment: @KorayTugay Maybe the book "Calendrical Calculations" (ISBN-13) might also be interesting for you (more about other calendars so you can see how general calendar dates can consist of various parts/fields/elements). I will surely buy the latest edition soon in order to implement more calendars in Java.